# Running a query across multiple entities in Google Cloud datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I currently have three indexes. Users, Votes, Features.

Features have an 'active' boolean property.
Votes have two properties, both indexed; the user's key and the feature's key.

What I'm trying to do is get all the votes the user has made on currently active features. Currently, I'm getting all the active features, then for each resulting feature I filter the votes based on the current user's id and the feature's id.

That's a lot of queries.

Some people suggested I make a single query using OR, or JOIN, or IN, but it appears that GQL doesn't have OR or JOIN, and that it's IN doesn't work with arrays.

Is it possible to handle it better than what I'm currently doing ? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Batch operations`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations).

Below is my suggesion to get all active features related to specific user.

> Note
>
> - To minimaize the query cost, below codes uses [`Keys-only queries`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#special_query_types).
>     And it is supposed that `Votes` key is like this: `{user_id}_{feature_id}`.
> - Below codes are dummy codes of Golang.

1) Get Votes related to specific user by `Keys-only query` (It is better to add limit for cost):

```
    query := datastore.NewQuery("Votes").Filter("UserID =", 123).KeysOnly().Limit(100)

    keys, err := client.GetAll(ctx, query, nil)
```

2) Get FeatureID by splitting Vote's key:

```
   featureIDs := make([]*datastore.Key, len(keys))

   for i, key := range keys {
       s := strings.Split(key, "_")
       userID, featureID := s[0], s[1]
       featureIDs[i] = &datastore.Key{ Name:featureID }
   }
```

3) Get features by `Batch operation`:

```
   var features []*Features
   client.GetMulti(ctx, featureIDs, features)
```

4) Filter features by active flag:

```
    for _, f := range features {
        if f.active {
           // this is active feature.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It sadly seems like the best way to do it for now.